# Buying stamps in Wellington Airport?

Tags: mail, wellington, wlg

I'm flying out of Wellington Int'l Airport soon.  Can I buy stamps at the airport?  And if yes, are they available on Sundays as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote from the airport's [FAQ](https://www.wellingtonairport.co.nz/at-the-airport/traveller-information/faqs/where-do-i-post-mail/):

> Stamps and some packaging can be purchased from Relay on Level 1. A mail box is located on level 1 of the main terminal building at the top of the escalator near the front doors in the check-in area.

[Opening hours](https://www.wellingtonairport.co.nz/at-the-airport/shopping/relay/) for Relay:

> 4.00am - 8.00pm Sunday - Friday 
>   4.00am - 7.00pm Saturday

Comment: Yup, you beat me to it!  For clarity, there are three Relays at the airport, and the only one that has stamps and the mailbox is the one on the Departures level behind check-in and in front of Gollum.  Once you've gone through security and immigration, it's too late.